# I cannot figure it out <App /> meaning. it is hard to google

Tags: javascript, reactjs, directory, render

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import "github-fork-ribbon-css/gh-fork-ribbon.css";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

code is this.  In last line.  I know ReactDom.render means but I cannot figure out what **<App />** means. especially "**/>**"

Comment: Google `JSX`, this may be the term you are missing

Comment: There's probably a class named App that extends the React .component inside ./App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`App` refers to the file imported on line 3:

```
import App from "./App";
```

Open `App.js` on the same directory to look at the component. If you used the `create-react-app`, it is probably the root component of your application.

Comment: Can I ask about "/>" in <app />?

Comment: HTML Closing tag.

Comment: ah!. thanks! Now I got it.  So it was not that important at all.